# XSLT: Getting rid of elements with duplicated text values and keeping one with latest timestamp

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-16T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-24T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-07-07T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-08-05T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Delivered</status>
        <timestamp>2022-09-02T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-13T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-08-01T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-07-03T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-13T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Is there a way using XSLT to remove `<entry>` elements with duplicated `<status>` values and to keep only the `<entry>` with the latest `<timestamp>` xs:dateTime value? The elements are in a random order with other many other possible status type values intermingled all under the `<root>` element.

My desired output:

```
 <root>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-07-07T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-08-05T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Delivered</status>
        <timestamp>2022-09-02T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-16T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-24T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-07-07T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-08-05T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Delivered</status>
        <timestamp>2022-09-02T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-13T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-08-01T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>Late</status>
        <timestamp>2022-07-03T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <status>On Time</status>
        <timestamp>2022-06-13T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="status">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<root>
  <entry>
    <status>On Time</status>
    <timestamp>2022-07-07T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <status>Late</status>
    <timestamp>2022-08-05T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <status>Delivered</status>
    <timestamp>2022-09-02T00:00:00Z</timestamp>
  </entry>
</root>
```